# Call a script from .js instead of html

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension

I would like to convert this [html](http://jsfiddle.net/maxim75/H3Wkr/) script into a chrome extension. I followed this short [tuto](https://www.sitepoint.com/create-chrome-extension-10-minutes-flat/) and apparently, I should move all the `script` ●parts into a `.js`file:

> Due to security constraints, we can’t put inline JavaScript into our
>   HTML files inside of our Chrome extensions, so we have to create a
>   separate file to hold any JavaScript code we need and we’ll reference
>   it from the HTML file.

So instead of having just this html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>  <html> 
    <head> 
    <title>My Page</title> 
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"> </head>  <body> 
    <div class="translate">Тестирование</p>
    <div class="translate_control" lang="en"></div>

    <script>
    function googleSectionalElementInit() {
      new google.translate.SectionalElement({
        sectionalNodeClassName: 'translate',
        controlNodeClassName: 'translate_control',
        background: '#f4fa58'
      }, 'google_sectional_element');
    }
    </script>
    <script src="//translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?cb=googleSectionalElementInit&ug=section&hl=en"></script>

</body> </html>
```

I should have one `html` ...:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    <div class="translate">Тестирование</p>
    <div class="translate_control" lang="en"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

...and one `.js`. But I am not sure how to go with the `.js`. How shoudl I call the script `//translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?cb=googleSectionalElementInit&ug=section&hl=en`. Also should I add the function `googleSectionalElementInit` inside a `document.addEventListener` function?

Also will the script work because it will be stored on my local computer and not a server?

Comment: I think you need to load it from https:// URL, not just //, using a standard `<script>` tag as in your first html. To do that in an extension you'll have add a few google domains used by the translation script to [`script-src` CSP in manifest.json](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy). Use devtools network monitor with the jsfiddle example to see which domains are actually used. Also inspect the existing extensions that use google translation script for hints/examples.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I include a JavaScript file in another JavaScript file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/950087/how-do-i-include-a-javascript-file-in-another-javascript-file)